# Как сделать свою рекламу на сайте что бы не обрезалась плагинами в браузере

Tags: html, php, javascript

Здравствуйте!

**Проблема:** на сайте рекламу обрезают додатки браузерные (AdBlock и другие)

Как сделать что бы додатоки не обрезали мою рекламу на сайте ?

Answer (score 6):

Вы не сможете предотвратить вырезание рекламы, в конце-концов, браузер пользователя волен интерпретировать HTML так, как ему вздумается.

Вы можете, однако, затруднить задание для браузера: размещать рекламу на своём сайте, использовать те же пути, что и нерекламные картинки и т. п. Тем не менее, в достаточной мере технически продвинутый пользователь обойдёт и это.

Лично я, сталкиваясь с сайтом, который активно противодействует блокировке рекламы, просто перестаю его посещать. Так что задумайтесь, так ли важна для Вас реклама?

Comment: [Какая реклама считается «ненавязчивой»?][1]


  [1]: http://adblockplus.org/ru/acceptable-ads

Comment: 80  - 90 % на сайте новые пользователи а реклама не навязчивая

Comment: @Дима: тогда, возможно, имеет смысл поговорить с разработчиками `adblockplus` и убедить их добавить Вас в список ненавязчивой рекламы? Wladimir Palant, насколько я понимаю, владеет также русским и украинским на элементарном уровне (если вдруг английский язык -- не Ваш конёк).

Answer (score 1):

обычно режется по имени файла (adv/advertise и многие другие), есть по ип/веб адресам заблокированных в программе сайтов

примерное решение: используйте нестандартные пути, не используйте в именах adv/advert/и т.п., не попадайте с черный список :)